# Solar powered Smartwatches

Tags: smart-device, calculators

[Solar powered calculator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar-powered_calculator)

Similar to Solar powered calculator, are there Smartwatches powered by Solar cells?

If Yes, Is it feasible to design & manufacture Solar powered Smartwatches?

Comment: I really like the idea, but I have not seen them

Comment: Are you looking for an actual smart watch with an OS on it and internet features? Or would you be also interested in fitness watches which have more limited capabilities?

Comment: Yes, it would be possible. No, it is not being done. Problem is that the IT adapted to a world where CPU/RAM doubles in every two years. Requiring really low power consumption would mean that we would need to re-think and re-develop the last decades. It won't happen. Consider that 20 years ago, it was enough to re-charge a phone once in a week. Now they need re-charge in a day. But it would be possible, only not in the current world. First it needs to be changed.

Comment: 20 years ago, phones didn't have huge screens, WIFI / Bluetooth, near-constant data traffic... Comparing mobile phones now to those 20 years ago, is like comparing a photograph to a TV...